# Apache Axis 1.4 OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, exception, out-of-memory, heap-memory, axis

I have a peculiar problem that have suddenly appeared on the client side that uses Apache Axis 1.4 to make SOAP requests to a web service. Everything has been running smoothly for a year. The size of the responses have been growing slowly over time, and recently I'm getting rather random `OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space` exceptions upon the call. The top part of the trace shown at the bottom. This happens at perhaps 1/10 of the calls made. If it happens and I catch the exception and just try the call again, it works in 99 cases out of 100.

When I first started seeing this, I naturally assumed that my maximum heap size needed to be increased. I'm running Tomcat 6, and changed my previous `-Xmx1024M` setting to `-Xmx2048M` (there's plenty of RAM on the machine). However, this didn't change anything. Looking at the status of Tomcat, the heap seems to have plenty of space to accomodate the SOAP response. The problem does not seem to be related to PermGen space available either.

The error is not related to the time the application have been running, it can happen immediately upon start of Tomcat. Hence it seems not related to the overall load on the server.

Does anybody have any ideas about this? Am I dealing with a known bug in Axis? I've found a few cases of people getting `OutOfMemoryError` exception when sending huge attachments over SOAP, however, this is not what I'm doing.

I'm using wrapped/literal for the SOAP web service.

```
Exception in thread "Thread-6" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
        at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder$objArrayVector.add(SAX2EventRecorder.java:254)
        at org.apache.axis.message.SAX2EventRecorder.newElement(SAX2EventRecorder.java:136)
        at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.pushNewElement(DeserializationContext.java:769)
        at org.apache.axis.message.SOAPHandler.startElement(SOAPHandler.java:94)
        at org.apache.axis.encoding.DeserializationContext.startElement(DeserializationContext.java:1048)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:504)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:376)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2732)
        at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:625)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the look of it, I'd say the problem is not with Axis. Did you try to perform a memory analysis? With a tool like Memory Analyzer Tool (MAT).

Comment: Hello, thanks for the input. I've used jvisualvm to monitor the memory usage, and Axis-related object instances account for a big part of the memory consumption. However, given that the size of the response has grown only in small chunks over the last months, and that a doubling of the available heap doesn't solve the problem, it seems very unlikely that actual lack of heap is the real problem. Also, would this be the case, I find it very strange that it works 9 times out of 10, and that things work immediately upon a retry after the error manifests itself.

Comment: Some more input, I found this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AXIS-2749 and my situation is very similar - i.e. it's a thread that repeatedly deserializes the SOAP response.

Comment: @MarcusJohansson did you find any solution for this problem? I am working on legacy application we are still using axis 1.4.